# Remove duplicated values in one column and return based newest value in another column

Tags: r

I have the following dataset i created so i can replicate my issue. I have Module/Filename that are duplicates.

```
owaspSample <- data.frame(Module=c("AccessDetails.java","AccessDiverse.java","BgField.java","BgStatus.java","CmdDate.java","CmdGameDate.java","CommentDate.java","CostDate.java","EntranceDetails.java","GameDate.java","LdPopDate.java","LeaseCostDate.java","PastApprovalDate.java","ProvisioningDate.java","ReservationDate.java","RefDate.java","ServiceDate.java","StatusDate.java","ProfileDate.java","UpdateCmdDate.java","ViewDate.java","AccessDetails.java","AccessDiverse.java","AuthenticationDate.java","CmdDate.java","CmdSummaryDate.java","CmdViewDate.java","ChangeOrderDate.java","CommentDate.java","CostDate.java","GameDate.java","LdPopDate.java","LeaseCostDate.java","PastApprovalDate.java","ReservationDate.java","RefDate.java","UnderwaterCmdDate.java","WaveDate.java","XmlFormatter.java"),
Category = c("SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","SQL Injection","XML External Entity Injection"),
scanDate=c("2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-23","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24","2016-10-24"),
VulnCount = c("13","15"," 1"," 3","15"," 2","11","30"," 2"," 2"," 2"," 2"," 4"," 2"," 3"," 9"," 1"," 1"," 1"," 8"," 6","25","28"," 3","30"," 1"," 6"," 5","20","23"," 3"," 3"," 4","10"," 3","17"," 1"," 3"," 2"),
Owasp = c("A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A00-SQL Injection","A01-Injection"))
```

I execute the following to remove duplicates and it seems to work. however, I want to be able to return the duplicate with the latest date. The date has to be dynamic.

```
owaspSample <- owaspSample[!duplicated(owaspSample$Module),]
```

For example if you encounter this:

```
Module                  Category        Date        VulnCount   Owasp
CostDate.java           SQL Injection   2016-10-23      30      A00-SQL Injection
EntranceDetails.java    SQL Injection   2016-10-23      2       A00-SQL Injection
GameDate.java           SQL Injection   2016-10-23      2       A00-SQL Injection
CostDate.java           SQL Injection   2016-10-24      23      A00-SQL Injection
GameDate.java           SQL Injection   2016-10-24      3       A00-SQL Injection
```

Expected output should be this:

```
Module                  Category        Date        VulnCount   Owasp
EntranceDetails.java    SQL Injection   2016-10-23      2       A00-SQL Injection
CostDate.java           SQL Injection   2016-10-24      23      A00-SQL Injection
GameDate.java           SQL Injection   2016-10-24      3       A00-SQL Injection
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: See the `fromLast` argument of `duplicated`.

Comment: nicola, thanks. That works at least it returns Modules based on latest date. however it is deleting files that are not duplicated. This dataset i provided the test works fine. Got figured out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used nicola's suggestion and added another piece of code `unique` and I do not loose files names that are not duplicated.

```
owaspSample <- owaspSample[unique(owaspSample$Module),]

owaspSample <- owaspSample[!duplicated(owaspSample$Module, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

I thought, they do the same thing. However together they are giving me expected results.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'Module', `slice` the last row in each group

```
library(dplyr)
owaspSample %>% 
         group_by(Module) %>%
         slice(n())
```